# How can I add a class to only the closest li if span text equals something?

Tags: jquery

I've been working on some jQuery code that will add a class to the *li* if the span text exist. This way it will add a different class to each *li*. How can I add each class to the *li* if the span text exists?

Here's what I have so far.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Adds SPAN tags
  $('.menu > ul > li > a').each(function() {
    $(this.firstChild).wrap('<span></span>');
  });

  if ($('.menu > ul > li:first-child > a > span').text() == "Dashboard") {

    $('span:contains("dashboard")').closest("li").addClass('dashboard');
  } else {
    $('.menu > ul > li').addClass('Returns False'); // Added this for testing only
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

The HTML currently looks like this

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a class="user_menu_link_selected" href="#">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li><a class="user_menu_link" href="#">Monitor</a>
      <li>
        <li><a class="user_menu_link" href="#">Admin</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="user_menu_link" href="#">FTP</a>
        </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is how I want it to look

```html
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="dashboard"><a class="user_menu_link_selected" href="#"><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
        <li class="monitor"><a class="user_menu_link" href="#"><span>Monitor</span></a><li>
        <li class="admin"><a class="user_menu_link" href="#"><span>Admin</span></a></li>
        <li class="ftp"><a class="user_menu_link" href="#"><span>FTP</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: selectors are case sensitive, `dashboard` is not on the content `Dashboard` is. Also if you use closest why use the other condition to check its text is Dashboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better if you change the initial markup.

But if you can't then it looks like the class name is the same as the text of the span so

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Adds SPAN tags
  $('.menu > ul > li > a').wrapInner('<span></span>');

  $('.menu > ul > li').addClass(function() {
    return $(this).find('> a > span').text().trim().toLowerCase()
  })
});
```

```css
.menu li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.menu span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.dashboard {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.monitor {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.admin {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
.ftp {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="user_menu_link_selected" href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a class="user_menu_link" href="#">Monitor</a></li>
        <li><a class="user_menu_link" href="#">Admin</a></li>
        <li><a class="user_menu_link" href="#">FTP</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

If the relation is not that simple then use a key value pair

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Adds SPAN tags
  $('.menu > ul > li > a').wrapInner('<span></span>');

  var map = {
    Dashboard: 'dashboard',
    Monitor: 'monitor',
    Admin: 'admin',
    FTP: 'ftp'
  }
  $('.menu > ul > li').addClass(function() {
    return map[$(this).find('> a > span').text().trim()]
  })
});
```

```css
.menu li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.menu span {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.dashboard {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.monitor {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.admin {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
.ftp {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="user_menu_link_selected" href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a class="user_menu_link" href="#">Monitor</a></li>
        <li><a class="user_menu_link" href="#">Admin</a></li>
        <li><a class="user_menu_link" href="#">FTP</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but is there a way to change the addClass function so it doesn't pickup the sub menus as I add them? the current code gets all the sub menus and adds them to the class as well.

Comment: @James30263 try the update `$(this).find('> a > span').text().trim()`

Comment: ...Quick question. If I add a another menu item to the var "map" that has a space it wont show up. For example I added TS3 Admin: 'ts3admin', Do you know how i would add this as well?

Comment: Nevermind...I got it... I added it as "TS3 Admin": 'ts3admin',